# Tkinter Text/ScrolledText new lines

Tags: python, text, tkinter, newline

When using a Tkinter Text widget, or ScrolledText widget, if you hit enter for a new line, what is the new line represented as in the text if you `get()` the text from that widget? And how could this be replaced with either `\n` or `<br>`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You get a `\n` for each new line (including a final `\n` which is always present).